# How to redirect to another route onDecodeError in nuxt2 using redirect-module

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js, sentry

I have a project that is built on nuxt 2 and I'm having an issue where I'm getting a lot of `URI Malformed` errors on Sentry from routes that are valid but has `%2` at the end of it which causes the error.

So I need a way to remove the `%2` whenever there is an error while decoding and redirect the user to that route.

How can I redirect the user to a different route onDecodeError?

I tried to do something like this:

```js
        onDecode: (req, res, next) => decodeURI(req.url),
        onDecodeError: (error, req, res, next) => {
            if (/^.*(%2)$/.test(req.url)) {
                res.setHeader('Location', encodeURI(req.url.slice(0, -2)))
            } else {
                next(error)
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got that sorted out

```js
            if (/^.*(%2)$/.test(req.url)) {
                res.setHeader('Location', encodeURI(req.url.slice(0, -2)))
                res.statusCode = 302
                res.end()
            } else {
                next(error)
            }
```

Comment: Hi, please accept your answer when you can.